# Git no longer asks me for my GitHub username and password. It now asks me for an "email". How do I get the old version?

Tags: git

My C:/ drive recently corrupted, it is over 6 years old of 24/7 use. I've reinstalled git, but now when committing and pushing to my repository, it asks me for an "email". This is not an issue, but it now blocks it from "exposing my email". I know how to allow command line pushes that expose my email, but I would much rather have the other way. I am almost certain I've messed up somewhere during installation. How should I fix this? Thank you!

Comment: git commits include a name and e-mail.  If you check the log in your old projects, you can see what e-mail you set up.

Comment: Furthermore I would recommend to use an SSH key, then you do not have to login to github at all